# How to change display resolution

Tags: display

How do I change the display resolution which has only one setting 640 x 480 to settings that will fit my laptop?

Comment: please try my answer and let me know :)

Comment: Problem is I have no choices there is only 640x480 in the list

Comment: please [edit] and add output of `xrandr`

Comment: does it detected the monitor? I have edited my answer

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like your monitor or your video card driver has not been detected correctly. What kind of video card do you have?

Answer (score 6):

First run:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Now logout/ login.

Go to settings --> Display

If you have multiple displays and they are not mirrored, you can have different settings on each display. Select a display in the preview area.

Select your desired resolution and rotation.

Click `Apply`. The new settings will be applied for 30 seconds before reverting back. That way, if you cannot see anything with the new settings, your old settings will be automatically restored. If you are happy with the new settings, click Keep This Configuration.

[image: Imgur]

Refer [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/look-resolution.html) for more info.

Comment: This worked great for me for Elementary OS . Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

Commenting on Ravans post from 2015, that worked perfectly. i noticed on the login screen before installing mesa-utils that the login screen was 1080p.

(im adding this because i just signed up)