# Pantheon-mail account configuration dialog doesn't fit in low-res displays

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-mail

I have an old notebook with a 1280x800 display and when I try to change an existing email account's configuration, the configuration dialog doesn't completely fit into the screen.
Bye.

Comment: Have you tried to see if your resolution can be set to a higher level: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3695/how-to-change-display-resolution

Comment: Yes, thanks. The graphic card can handle higher resolutions but 1280x800 is the physical limit of the display. I think is a matter of usability, because the graphical interface should handle any screen resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround, you can move the dialog with <kbd>Win</kbd>+mouse drag.

Comment: Ok, thanks.
Do you think I should rise this issue as a bug, posting it in launchpad or this community is somehow connected to the developers' community, so that they could read this post and include it in the bug list?

Comment: You can report it as a bug there is no "magic connection" :)